# Include all options in .latexmkrc (or similar)

Tags: latexmk

Is there a way to compile in a similar way than make uses the Makefile with latexmk?

What I mean is that I often run `latexmk filename -pdf -pvc`. Whould there be a way of specifying the `filename -pdf -pvc` in a file like `.latexmkrc` so I could just type `latexmk` and it would compile accodring to the options specified in that file?

Comment: I am not much familiar with latexmk, but do you know arara? With arara, there is I think an option to write your own arararc file, which I think can have a lot of rules or options for you to specify. Also, arara can be used in compliance with latexmk.

Comment: Latexmk is a Perl script, the option handling is not that hard to understand, so I'd just recommend looking in the script it self to figure out which variables need which values. Though I would not enable pvc by default (I don't remember if there is a switch off continuous option), I use aliases for that. I have the equivalent to -pdf in my rc file and have lpvc be an alias for `latexmk -pvc... ` with some extra options that I do not remember (I enable it to stop compiling upon the first error)

Comment: To add to daleif's comment: The relevant information is in the documentation. For -pvc there is a variable $preview_continuous_mode.  If `latexmk` is run without a filename on the command line, it will process all .tex files in the directory it is run in. However, that won't work in -pvc mode if there is more than one file.  But then you can set @default_files to restrict what's processed,